# recuperar fecha de una llamada ajax en struts

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, struts2

Tengo que recuperar desde java una fecha que se pasa como parámetro en la url de la llamada ajax. El parámetro en la Url desde la llamada ajax lo obtiene bien, el problema viene desde la parte java que es null.

```
if(id=='A'){
                tipoFacturaV="A";
                newSerie=proponerNewSerie();
                url='/sgca/cabnom/duplicarFacturaAnulacion.action?tipoFacturaV='+tipoFacturaV+'&numNomDuplicado='+newNumNom+'&cabnom.tipoFacturaV=${cabnom.tipoFacturaV}&factCli.NFactura=${factCli.NFactura}&factCli.SFactura=${factCli.SFactura}&cabnom.numnom=${cabnom.numnom}&operation=new&factCli.cabnom.numnom=${factCli.cabnom.numnom}&factCli.FFactura=${factCli.FFactura}';
                alert(url);
            }
            else if(id=='S' || id=='I'){
                tipoFacturaV=id;
                newSerie=proponerNewSerie();

                //url='/sgca/producto/buscarModal.action';
                url='/sgca/cabnom/duplicarFacturaRectificacion.action?tipoFacturaV='+tipoFacturaV+'&numNomDuplicado='+newNumNom+'&cabnom.tipoFacturaV=${cabnom.tipoFacturaV}&factCli.NFactura=${factCli.NFactura}&factCli.SFactura=${factCli.SFactura}&cabnom.numnom=${cabnom.numnom}&operation=new&factCli.cabnom.numnom=${factCli.cabnom.numnom}&cabnom.motivoRx='+motivoRx+'';

            }
            $.ajax(url, {
                async:false,
                type:'post',
                success: function(data){
                    window.location='/sgca/cabnom/view_fact.action?operation=edit&pestanya=LINEASNOM'+'&cabnom.numnom='+newNumNom+ 
                    '&duplicada=true';

                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("Se ha producido un error a la hora de duplicar la nominación.");
                }
            });
```

[image: salida url]

en la imagen muestro la url. `factCli.FFactura=2018-01-18` es la fecha que tengo que recuperar desde java. Muestro la calse java con la variable, sus getter y setter

```
@TableAnnotation(tableName="FACTURA_VENTA")
public class FacturaVenta {
@ColumnAnnotation(colName="F_FACTURA")
private Date fFactura;
@TypeConversion (converter="com.sgca.web.converter.FechaConverter") 
public Date getFFactura() {
    return fFactura;
}
public void setFFactura(Date fFactura) {
    this.fFactura = fFactura;
  }
 }
```

y éste es el action al que se llama desde javascript, y donde tengo que recuperar la fecha.

```
public String duplicarFacturaAnulacion(){
    System.out.println("llamando al metodo duplicarFacturaAnulacio del action ");
    int numNomAnterior = this.getCabnom().getNumnom();
    this.cabnom = this.cabNomService.read(this.cabnom.getNumnom());
    this.buscarLineasNom();
        //S_FACTURA_ORI
        this.cabnom.setSFacturaOri(factCli.getSFactura());
        //N_FACTURA_ORI
        this.cabnom.setNFacturaOri(factCli.getNFactura());
        //TIPO_FACTURA_V
        this.cabnom.setTipoFacturaV(tipoFacturaV);
        //F_FACTURA_ORI
        this.cabnom.setFFacturaOri(factCli.getFFactura());//factCli.getFFactura() null
}
```

`factCli.getFFactura()` es `null`, pero en la URL si lo recupera.

El resto de parámetros que le paso en la URL de la llamada `ajax` los obtengo sin problemas, sin embargo, la fecha es null. No se si es que tengo que hacer algún parseo de la fecha desde java para recuperarla. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Con la información que muestras no veo por dónde puede estar el problema. ¿Podrías añadir el código del converter? ¿Es posible que si encuentra algún problema de conversión esté "tragándose" la excepción y devolviendo `null`?

Comment: Y algún log para saber si el converter y el setter se están llamano y qué valores les llegan estaría bien.

Comment: Efectivamente @SJuan76, era un problema en la conversión de la fecha. En el método `public String duplicarFacturaAnulacion()` he añadido `SimpleDateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   this.cabnom.setFFacturaOri(df.parse(fFactura));` y solucionado.